# Should the Awakening Center be rezed to host cards?

Tags: android-netrunner

Do I need to rez the [Awakening Center](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03021) to install cards on it, or it can host them even being face down?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by default cards need to be active (in the case of an Upgrade like Awakening Center, this means rezzed) in order for their card text to be used.

From the [Rules Reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/03/e1/03e12a8e-3d21-4a6a-af2d-5edd99f61c4e/adn_rules_reference_hi.pdf):

> **Active**
>
> A state in which a card’s abilities are able to be used and affect
>   the game. This generally only applies to cards installed and
>   faceup in the play area, but also includes the identities of both
>   players and agendas in the Corp’s score area.
>
> Unless otherwise stated, Runner cards are played and installed
>   active into the play area.
>
> Unless otherwise stated, Corp cards are installed unrezzed, and
>   thus inactive, into the play area and are made active by rezzing
>   them. Operations are played active into the play area while they
>   resolve.

and conversely:

> **Inactive**
>
> A state in which a card’s abilities are unable to be used or affect
>   the game. Even though they do not affect the game, inactive
>   cards retain their printed characteristics (name, card type,
>   faction, cost, subtypes, influence, etc).
>
> Runner cards are generally inactive in the heap, grip, and stack
>   until installed into the play area. Agendas in the Runner’s score
>   area are inactive.
>
> In addition to being inactive in R&D, HQ, and Archives, Corp
>   cards are generally installed unrezzed, and thus inactive.
>
> If an ability explicitly mentions an effect from a regularly
>   inactive state, or if it can only work while the card is inactive,
>   then that ability can still trigger and affect the game. This
>   includes:
>
> •   “When accessed...” abilities on cards, which still trigger
>   even while the card is inactive.
>
> •   Abilities that state they trigger from an inactive zone
>   can still be triggered and used even though the card is
>   normally inactive in that zone.
>
> •   Effects that modify how or when a card can be played
>   or installed affect that card and the game even while the
>   card would normally be inactive.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, card text is only active on rezzed cards. Awakening center must be rezzed to host ice.